# Django - count numbers of same field in a model

Tags: django, model, django-queryset, imagefield

I'm new to Django and I'm building an e-commerce website (db: sqlite3). Each item on sale has 1-5 images uploaded. So I've got the model here:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    '''Item model with maximum 5 images uploaded'''

    <--snip-->

    image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/')
    image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
    image_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
    image_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
    image_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
```

In order to create a *carousel* (bootstrap4) for each item, I need to know how many images uploaded. My thinking is to create a function in the class to find out how many `ImageField` there are in this model and how many are not blank.

So my question is:
1. is there a better way to create ImageField, a more dynamic way?
2. is it possible to find out the number of the same field in a model that are not blank?

Comment: Does the `Item` model only have image filed or other fields as well?

Comment: yes there are many other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate model for the images and link it to the Item model. This will make filtering easier as well as make image uploads more flexible.

```
class ItemImage(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/')

class Item(models.Model):
    <--snip-->

    # we add a model property then do a reverse lookup in order to 
    # count images linked to the item object
    # this can then be accessed by item_obj.image_count
    @property
    def get_image_count(self)
        return self.itemimage_set.all().count()
```

Comment: This came across my mind as well but I thought it was much easier to create an item in one session on one single page with django admin...

Comment: You can use the `TabularInline` django class in order to easily/dynamically add more images on the same page. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)